# Another cash machine with special bill values in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, iteration

**Task:**

An ATM dispenses banknotes with the following values/denominations: {5, 30, 35, 40, 150, 200}. The user should be able to repeatedly enter an amount divisible by 5 without leaving a remainder. The denomination of banknotes with the smallest possible number of notes should be issued that corresponds to the amount. Recursive calls are not allowed to use.

**Questions:**

Can you take a look at my code? Are the variable names unique? Is the approach ok, or is there anything to improve? What is the best way to calculate the depth constant?

```java
    /**
     * This utility method calculates the minimal amounts of bills (5, 30, 35, 40, 150, 200) needed for a given amount.
     * The amount argument should be between 0 and 10000 and be divisible by 5.
     *
     * @param amount the amount (between 0 and 10000 and divisible by 5) to be patched
     * @return an array with the minimal amounts of bills needed
     */
    public static int[] patch(final int amount) {
        if (amount < 0 || amount > 10000 || amount % 5 != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid amount");
        }

        final int[] bills = {5, 30, 35, 40, 150, 200};
        final int depth = Math.min(amount / bills[0] + 1, 50);
        // (How can you calculate the best depth here?)

        int bestCount = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int[] bestResult = new int[bills.length];
        int[] indexes = new int[bills.length];

        a:
        for (int i = 0; ; ) {
            // calculates the current count of bills and sum
            int count = 0;
            int sum = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < indexes.length; j++) {
                count += indexes[j];
                sum += indexes[j] * bills[j];
            }

            // checks if the current count is the best, and terminates this iteration if no further solution can be found
            if (amount - sum <= 0) {
                if (amount - sum == 0 && count <= bestCount) {
                    bestCount = count;
                    System.arraycopy(indexes, 0, bestResult, 0, indexes.length);
                }
                indexes[i] = depth - 1;
            }

            // increments the indexes (or leaves the entire loop)
            indexes[i]++;
            if (indexes[i] == depth) {
                do {
                    indexes[i] = 0;
                    i++;
                    // overflow protection , time to leave
                    if (i == indexes.length) {
                        break a;
                    }
                } while (indexes[i] == depth);
                indexes[i]++;
                i = 0;
            }
        }

        return bestResult;
    }
```

Comment: I corrected my spelling. Sorry, I hope the task is clearer and understandable now.

Comment: Have you read about the [change making problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem)?

Comment: You should perform the Pearson Test to show whether your (somewhat strange) coin system can be optimally solved using a simpler greedy algorithm.

Comment: I corrected spelling, not the problem description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## cite your references

This is a well known problem.
But you do not appear to be using a well known solution technique.
That is, this code is "tricky".
(It seems to be using Dynamic Programming, but I'm at a loss
to describe the meaning of what it stores.)

Tell us what approach you're using,
perhaps by citing a blog, textbook, or wikipedia article.
Then the Gentle Reader can follow along,
tracing the corresponding elements between article and code,
to verify that each element is correctly implemented.
As written, you have needlessly made that a more difficult process.

---

## repetition

Thank you for the introductory javadoc.

```
     * This ....
     * The amount argument should be between 0 and 10000 and be divisible by 5.
     *
     * @param amount the amount (between 0 and 10000 and divisible by 5) to be patched
```

[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
up that second sentence; simply delete it.
It's completely redundant with the very helpful `@param amount` description.

Why do we keep our code DRY?
Suppose the max increased to `20_000` a few months down the road.
Now we have to not only keep revised code + @param doc in sync,
but we have to chase down other instances as well.
We try to minimize the number of occurrences that might drift out of sync.
That makes *all* of our documentation more believable,
even documentation for shopworn code.

---

## design of Public API

```
        final int[] bills = {5, 30, 35, 40, 150, 200};
```

It's kind of weird that the function signature doesn't accept such an array,
given that the return value is very much in terms of these denominations.

Alternatively we should give some distinctive name to this currency system,
and use a related name for the function, showing it is a special purpose
function that is tightly linked to that system.

On which topic: This function is named `patch` ?!? What?
I can't imagine how that's relevant.
I would have expected a name like `dispenseBills` or perhaps `makeChange`.

---

## diagnostic message

```
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid amount");
```

This is some lovely error checking, you can certainly retain it as-is.

But imagine that application code triggered this error,
and some poor maintenance engineer reading the web logs
needs to track down the details, to figure out which component
did the Wrong Thing and should be repaired.
First question that comes to mind will be "what was the amount?"
Did it run afoul of the negative check? Too big? Lacked a factor of five?

We can make that debugging process a little easier by
throwing an error with formatted string which includes the amount in question.

---

## dynamic allocation

```
        final int depth = Math.min(amount / bills[0] + 1, 50);
```

This expression does not seem well motivated.
The worst case would be `min(2_001, 50)`,
and those two numbers don't seem to be of very different magnitude to me;
it's just a "small" difference in memory allocation, a factor of forty.
We made a
[promise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
up in the javadoc, we *will* deliver "minimal amounts of bills"
if caller did the right thing.
And we verified the right thing when we did the precondition check.

Turning a total function into partial one, to save a little RAM,
doesn't seem wise and in any event it certainly requires documentation
of this new potential failure mode.

Better to design such details out of the system.
You don't want to allocate zeros which typically will never be used?
Fine. Rather than using a "hard to size" static datastructure such as array,
prefer a dynamic datastructure such as HashMap.
With Integer keys, it offers you the same interface.

```
        // (How can you calculate the best depth here?)
```

If you choose to retain `depth` then you'll want to include a
[GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) calculation.
Imagine we drop the "divisible by 5" requirement,
report "impossible" by returning all zero counts or throwing an error,
and adopt this alternate currency system:

```
        final int[] altBillValues = {29, 30, 35, 40, 150, 200};
```

Then even with the `10_000` ceiling,
we would definitely need a much greater maximum depth.

---

## while loop

This is a bit weird:

```
        a:
        for (int i = 0; ; ) {
                    ...
                    if ( ... ) {
                        break a;
```

You had an opportunity to name that location, but used meaningless `a` instead.
Sigh!

Here is more standard control flow that you might use:

```
        i = 0;
        while ( ... ) {
                    ...
```

That leaves us with deciding what predicate the `while` should use, different from the `while (True)` that OP essentially uses.
I am a little surprised that we're not comparing "amount dispensed so far"
against "amount we were asked to dispense".

This all seems to be fallout from the decision to artificially impose
a "max depth" constraint, something that was not present in the original
problem definition.
Perhaps the OP algorithm always terminates, but from a cursory reading
there's no obvious loop variant that always drives us closer to
termination. If the maximum allowed depth was "small", say `4`, it appears
the algorithm could `return bestResult` containing wrong bill counts.
The current control structure does not inspire confidence in correctness.
Resizing the array when needed, or relying on a HashMap, would simplify the code.

---

## positive infinity

This is very clear:

```
        int bestCount = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

These? Less so.

```
                indexes[i] = depth - 1;
                ...
            indexes[i]++;
            if (indexes[i] == depth) {
```

We seem to be dancing around the notion of positive infinity here,
in a needlessly complex way. If a comparison of `indexes[i] >= depth`
denotes "solution impossible" we could get away with slightly less
complex code. Designing such artifacts out of the solution entirely
seems preferable.

---

## naming

This potentially is a good identifier:

```
        final int[] bills = {5, 30, 35, 40, 150, 200};
```

But it turns out to be a little on the vague side,
given that bills are central to the problem we're solving.
Consider using `billValues` instead.

`amount` is a good parameter name.
Again a little on the vague side, consider `desiredAmount`. No biggie.

`bestCount` is a good name, but we maybe don't need it at all,
since it's redundant with sum of `bestResult`.
A helper function could recompute it as needed.

OTOH `indexes` is a truly terrible name, which should have been `billCounts`.
It appears many times, and obscures the meaning of the code.
With such a rename, rather than "result" go for parallel structure
with a name like `bestCounts` or `bestBillCounts`.

The identifiers `i`, `j`, `count`, `sum` are all perfect as-is.

---

## obscure tests

```
            if (amount - sum <= 0) {
                if (amount - sum == 0 && count <= bestCount) {
```

It's unclear why that's the best way to phrase the checks, instead of:

```
            if (amount <= sum) {
                if (amount == sum && count <= bestCount) {
```

It *might* have been the best way if there was a difference
we were tracking through the code, perhaps a difference that is
part of a loop variant, or that appears in a cited reference.
But as it stands it's just a cognitive speed bump.

---

This codebase appears to achieve a subset of its design goals.

I would not be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.
Recommend "discard and begin again, with a cited standard algorithm",
rather than "refactor the existing code".

You might choose to tackle a simpler variant first.
Ignore the "no recursion!" requirement, and produce a
[well-tested](https://junit.org/junit5)
recursive solution. With that in hand, you'll be in
a good position to refactor it into a solution where you
manually maintain a stack or you maintain a
[DP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) array.

Comment: Thanks for your review. 'Recommend "discard and begin again, with a cited standard algorithm", rather than "refactor the existing code"' I disagree with that. Yes, it is some kind of DP, or a "manually recursion algorithm", and I don't know the exact name of it. But I don't think the code is so bad that I want to start over with a completely different algorithm. I agree with all other remaining points.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for sharing your code.

### Are the variable names unique?

The point about variable names (or identifiers in general) is *not* uniqueness but **readability**, that is: *Do my identifiers express what its happening to a stranger (which will be yourself in 6 month...) in therms of the business logic implemented?*

To me as a present stranger

- the meaning of `depth` does not reveal itself at all, but that may be because I'm not a native English speaking accountant.
- the meaning of `indexes` seams to be the count of the individual bills in the result and is also not well named.
- the meaning of `bestResult` is unclear since there are no other results that would require marking this as "the best".

### What is the best way to calculate the depth constant?

Since I didn't get the meaning of `dept`I don't know.

### Is the approach ok, or is there anything to improve?

The naming needs improvement obviously.

The approach itself looks a little inconsistent to me, a mixture of OO an procedural programming.

> A pure procedural approach would have simply calculated the count of each bill value by dividing the (leftover) amount by the current bill value starting with the  biggest bill.

> A pure OO approach would have represented the bills as `enum` constants and added them in a single `List` instead of arrays.

The use of `break` together with a label is  very discouraged. It's the mild form of `goto` which is a reserved word without meaning in Java for a reason...

Finally, you name your method a "utility method".
There is a common misconception out there, that static methods are considered "utility". **This is wrong.**
You should always have a good reason to use the `static` keyword on methods and this reason should be: "I guarantee, betting my life, that there never will be another version of this method, a calling part of the program might like to select at runtime via polymorphism!"
Usually you loose this bet when you start unittesting, since you want to use test doubles for this method when testing other units that call this.

Comment: I don't find this answer helpful, especially the comment about static, but I don't want to downvote it either. Thanks anyway.