# Another ATMs cash-out (denomination) algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, array, dynamic-programming

Related to [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/287671/276703) and [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/287678/276703), I would like to have a second review from you on a modified version.

**The problem I tried to solve**

Some kind of "Minimum count of numbers required from given array to represent S" (see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-count-of-numbers-required-from-given-array-to-represent-s/)).

**Algorithms that I used**

Some kind of dynamic programming array (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)), but I don't know the exact name.

**Java Code**

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CashMachineWithDynamicProgrammingArray {
    private final int[] billValues;
    private final int[] billAmounts;
    private final int maxBillAmount;
    private int currentBillAmountIndex = 0;

    public CashMachineWithDynamicProgrammingArray(final int[] billValues, final int maxDepth) {
        this.billValues = billValues;
        billAmounts = new int[billValues.length];
        maxBillAmount = maxDepth;
    }

    private boolean next() {
        billAmounts[currentBillAmountIndex]++;
        if (billAmounts[currentBillAmountIndex] >= maxBillAmount) {
            do {
                billAmounts[currentBillAmountIndex] = 0;
                currentBillAmountIndex++;
                if (currentBillAmountIndex >= billAmounts.length) {
                    currentBillAmountIndex = 0;
                    return false;
                }
            } while (billAmounts[currentBillAmountIndex] >= maxBillAmount);
            billAmounts[currentBillAmountIndex]++;
            currentBillAmountIndex = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void skipCurrentBillIndexIncrementation() {
        billAmounts[currentBillAmountIndex] = maxBillAmount;
    }

    private int calculateBillsAmount() {
        int amount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < billValues.length; i++) {
            amount += billValues[i] * billAmounts[i];
        }
        return amount;
    }

    private int calculateBillsSum() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (final int billAmount : billAmounts) {
            sum += billAmount;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public int[] calculateBillAmountsWithLowestSum(final int amountToLookFor) {
        int lowestSum = 0;
        int[] billAmountsWithLowestSum = new int[billValues.length];
        do {
            int amount = calculateBillsAmount();
            if (amount >= amountToLookFor) {
                if (amount == amountToLookFor) {
                    int sum = calculateBillsSum();
                    if (lowestSum == 0 || sum < lowestSum) {
                        lowestSum = sum;
                        System.arraycopy(billAmounts, 0, billAmountsWithLowestSum, 0, billAmounts.length);
                    }
                }
                skipCurrentBillIndexIncrementation();
            }
        } while (next());
        return billAmountsWithLowestSum;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        int[] billValues = {1, 29, 59, 109, 209, 509, 1000, 2000, 5000};
        int maxDepth = 5;
        CashMachineWithDynamicProgrammingArray cashMachine = new CashMachineWithDynamicProgrammingArray(billValues, maxDepth);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cashMachine.calculateBillAmountsWithLowestSum(1)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cashMachine.calculateBillAmountsWithLowestSum(30)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cashMachine.calculateBillAmountsWithLowestSum(5000)));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cashMachine.calculateBillAmountsWithLowestSum(25114)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **banknote** for name of physical currency and **withdrawl** for the target/requested amount. I think this solves most of the program's understandability problem.

---

Name things for what they are, not how they are implemented.

`CashMachineWithDynamicProgrammingArray`  --->   `CashMachine`

---

`skipCurrentBillIndexIncrementation`

Do not make a method out of that one code line.

- "skip" means to pass over or ignore, so why is there a method that does nothing?
- The method does not do what it says. It is setting a default value, it is not skipping.
- The surrounding code logic is doing the skipping. This method is only the processing of that condition.
- Even with an accurate name the method hurts understanding. After all the details of working with array indexes, buried 3 "if"s deep you hide the detail of an "else" fall-through branch. A very simple detail it turns out. Ouch.

---

`calculateBillSum` - "calculate" is superfluous. "Sum" is a verb (in this use) and very specific - add a list of numbers. "calculate" can mean anything.

---

It is OK to name methods as if they are properties because it is a given that properties return values.

`calculateBillAmountsWithLowestSum`   --->  `BillLowestSum` or `LowestBillSum`

---

for-each makes code shorter, cleaner, and easier on the eyes.

---

Physically order the algorithm methods with `cashMachine.calculateBillAmountsWithLowestSum` at the top and the rest in depth/call order.

---

Return immediately on terminating conditions.

Nested redundant evaluation is bad. It hides simpler logic that must stand out.

```
     if (amount >= amountToLookFor) {
            if (amount == amountToLookFor) {
```

Much Better:

```
     if (amount > amountToLookFor) { addLargestBanknote(); }

     if (amount == amountToLookFor) {
        int sum = calculateBillsSum();
        
        if (lowestSum == 0 || sum < lowestSum) {
            lowestSum = sum;
            System.arraycopy(billAmounts, 0, billAmountsWithLowestSum, 0, billAmounts.length);
        }
     }
   } while (next());

    return billAmountsWithLowestSum;     
 }
```

Blank space around conditional code blocks really, totally, for sure, helps comprehension speed and readability.

NOTE: After this refactoring - and "skip..." method name change - I take back almost everything I said about that method earlier.

---

Cover all conditions.

The refactor above made me realize there is no 'less than' condition. Never say it will never happen.

If the oversight is intentional, add a comment. Alternatively add a line of code that "skips" for that condition.

However if higher level / caller code explicitly takes care of the possibility then ignoring it is ok. The Object constructor is the best place to set complete, valid execution state.

Comment: You forgot: Even if "amount == amountToLookFor" is true, "addLargestBanknote()" should be called (in both cases, a better solution cannot be found with the current combination). That was one of the reasons I nested the if conditions (avoid DRY).

Comment: then do you even need that first `if (amount >= amountToLookFor)`? Or do does it serve to not execute it in the implied  'less than' condition? If so I'd write  'less than' explicitly and still avoids the nested redundant 'equals'

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this is really broken in many ways.

It starts at a readability issue by using the word "amount" for two different meanings: the number of bills and the total value of bills. This makes the code very difficult to understand.

Then, what is `maxDepth` (or `maxBillAmount`)? Why does the same thing have two different names? Why isn't it calculated by the algorithm itself? By setting it to the arbitrarily value of `5` it breaks the algorithm. Try running the example for values between `6` and `28`.

The algorithm also seems to be broken or at least extraordinarily inefficient. Even for the trivial case of `1` the code runs through all (I believe 10.000.000) combinations of bills. One reason for this maybe because you are using the same `billAmounts` array for each call of `calculateBillAmountsWithLowestSum` with its old contents from the previous call. `billAmounts` and `currentBillAmountIndex` need to be local variables in `calculateBillAmountsWithLowestSum` and not a fields of the class.

Comment: Thanks. "code runs through all (I believe 10.000.000) combinations of bills." not through all, there is some kind of "pruning"... but true, for `maxDepth` `5` and values between `6` and `28` he wouldn't find a solution. There might be another answer to come, otherwise I would mark this as the most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) variables holding and methods returning `boolean` values sould start with `is...`, `has...`, `can...` or alike. So your method `next()` might better be named `isCalculationCompleted()` (inverting its current logic...).

Also it looks like you are "hiding" the actual alorithm fro finding the number of a certain bill needed in this `next()` method.

Comment: "next()" does several things other than just return a boolean value, I don't think the JNCs are directly applicable here.

Comment: @TobiasGrothe Don't you thing that questioning your design would be more appropriate then questioning the JNC? Don't you value the single responsibility pattern?

Comment: I'm not criticizing the naming conventions, but rather applying them incorrectly. As I said, "next()" also contains application logic.

Comment: @TobiasGrothe: *"As I said, "next()" also contains application logic."* **--** As I said, that is a design problem.

Comment: Then, every Iterator has a design problem in Java...

Comment: @TobiasGrothe *"Then, every Iterator has a design problem in Java"* **--** Strictly yes. ;o) The difference between the Java lib Iterators and your `next()` method is that they just advance to the next element while you have your complete application logic there...

Comment: Ok, that's a little easier to understand now. But not "the complete logic" - only the index increment step... On the other hand, this step is a part of the logic, yes. Let's discuss further in chat - if there is a need.